# How are these strings represented internally in Python interpreter ? I don't understand

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = 'éáűőúöüó€'
print type(a)    # <type 'str'>
print a          # éáűőúöüó€
print ord(a[-1]) # 172
```

Why is this working ? Shouldn't be this a `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ...` ? There are unicode literals in the string.

When I prefix it with `u`, the results are different:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = u'éáűőúöüó€'
print type(a)    # <type 'unicode'>
print a          # éáűőúöüó€
print ord(a[-1]) # 8364
```

Why? What is the difference between the internal representations in python ? How can I see it myself ? :)

Comment: Why should it be a syntax error to have bytes in a byte string?

Comment: Ok, so what is the first string and what is the second ?

Comment: The first is a `str` object containing the UTF-8 bytes that are in the file. The second is a `unicode` object formed by decoding the UTF-8. Use `repr()` to see the difference.

Comment: Check the length of the string in the first case.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a legitimate question. To ask any clearer would require knowledge of the answer.

Comment: FYI, this is fixed in Python 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> There are unicode literals in the string

No, there are not. There are bytes in the string. Python simply goes with the bytes your editor saved to disk when you created the file.

When you prefixed the string with a `u''`, you signalled to python that you are creating a `unicode` object instead. Python now pays attention to the encoding you specified at the top of your source file, and it *decodes* the bytes in the source file to a `unicode` object based on the encoding you specified.

In both cases, your editor saved a series of bytes to a file, for the `€` character, the UTF-8 encoding is *three* bytes, represented in hexadecimal as E282AC. The last byte in the bytestring is thus AC, or 172 in decimal. Once you decode the last 3 bytes as UTF-8, they together become the Unicode codepoint U+20AC, which is 8364 in decimal.

You really should read up on Python and Unicode:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Comment: Wow, great answer thanks ! I already read the first link still didn't understand the difference. Now it's crystal clear ! :)