# How is unicode represented internally in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-internals

How is Unicode string literally represented in Python's memory?

For example I could visualize `'abc'` as its equivalent ASCII bytes in Memory. Integer could be thought of as the 2's compliment representation. However `u'\u2049'`, even though is represented in `UTF-8` as `'\xe2\x81\x89'` - 3 bytes long, how do I visualize the literal `u'\u2049'` codepoint in the memory?

Is there a specific way it is stored in memory? Does Python 2 and Python 3 treat it differently?

Few related questions for anyone curious :

1) [How are these strings represented internally in Python interpreter ? I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839028/how-are-these-strings-represented-internally-in-python-interpreter-i-dont-und)

2) [What is internal representation of string in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838170/what-is-internal-representation-of-string-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know about CPython, the standard implementation. Python 2 and Python 3.0-3.2 use either UCS2<sup>*</sup> or UCS4 for Unicode characters, meaning it'll either use 2 bytes or 4 bytes for *each character*. Which one is picked is a compile-time option.

`\u2049` is then represented as either `\x49\x20` or `\x20\x49` or `\x49\x20\x00\x00` or `\x00\x00\x20\x49` depending on the native byte order of your system and if UCS2 or UCS4 was picked. ASCII characters in a unicode string still use 2 or 4 bytes per character too.

Python 3.3 switched to a new internal representation, using the most compact form needed to represent all characters in a string. Either 1 byte, 2 bytes or 4 bytes are picked. ASCII and Latin-1 text uses just 1 byte per character, the rest of the BMP characters require 2 bytes and after that 4 bytes is used.

See [PEP-393: *Flexible String Representation*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) for the full low-down on these representations.

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically speaking the UCS-2 build uses UTF-16, as non-BMP characters use UTF-16 surrogates to encode to 4 bytes (2 UTF-16 characters) each. However, Python documentation still refers to this as UCS2.

This does lead to unexpected behaviour such as the `len()` on non-BMP unicode strings being longer than the number of characters contained.

Comment: To know whether you have a "narrow" (UCS2) or "wide" (UCS4) build, examine sys.maxunicode.  65535 means narrow, 1114111 means wide.

Comment: I think technically, it's UTF-16 or UTF-32, not UCS2 or UCS4, since surrogate pairs are used in narrow builds, making it UTF-16.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: indeed, not sure why the documentation is still sticking to using UCS however.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: but for Python 3, you *can* call it UCS2 and UCS4 again as non-BMP characters are expressed using the full 4 bytes.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: From what I understand UTF-32 is merely a subset of UCS4 in that bytes outside the Unicode standard are not to be used; so the 4-byte build can be said to use both UTF-32 and UCS4.

Comment: it is UCS-2 because python allows strings that can't be interpreted as utf-16 e.g., lone surrogates: `b'\xdc\x00'.decode('utf-16be')`. Also, `len()` is invalid only on UCS-2 builds (utf-16 representation would produce a correct length).

Comment: Are you saying that `len()` does not count the number of Unicode code points in the string, but instead computes the length of the encoding of the string in memory?

Comment: @Joe: No; string objects store the number of unicode points in a variable, and `len()` returns that variable value. However, in _old_ Python versions (no longer supported) that used UCS2, if you stored a non-BMP codepoint then those would count as *two* characters instead of one. E.g. `len(u"\U0001D49E")` (or `len(u"\N{MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL C}")`) returns `2` in those versions, because in UCS2 that codepoint is represented by `\ud835\udc9e`.

Comment: I might be getting terminology confused because this is all new to me, but are you saying that the old version would store the single codepoint `u"\U0001D49E"` as the two codepoints `\ud835` and `\udc9e`? or are you saying that `\ud835\udc9e` is only a single codepoint, but the old version would return 2 because the old version did not return the number of codepoints?